# C++ Best optimize way to check matches in multidimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, matching

i have multidimensional array for example :

```
int arr[4][3] ={{12, 29, 11, 22},
                {14, 22, 22, 22},
                {14, 14, 67, 22},
                {14, 18, 14, 45}};
```

now i like to find match by pre defined rules for example:
find all "22" numbers that are in horizontal and more then 2 in a raw (line 1 i the array)
or 
find all the "14" numbers that are vertical and more then 2 in the vertical line (line 1,2,3) 
and also in Hypotenuse order (line [1,0],[2,1],[3,2])
now i know that i can scan the array for each rules and keep macing vectors
but is say the array is 15x15 and i have 20 rules it can be very messy
is there some kind of pattern or algorithm for this ?
in the end i like to simulate something like slot machine matching pay lines

Comment: I would represent it internally as one-dimensional array, and just use the specific methods to access it in row-like or column-like fashion. This makes it less messy for that kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

Break each rule into two parts.

- First part just depends on the contents of a cell.
- Second part depends on the pattern.

Scan the entire array only once. For cells matching the first part set a bit in a mask.  After the scan is done, use logical operations to match the patterns in the second part.  Depending on the rules, you might have one bitmask for each value that you match in the array.

For example, take the rules of 1) more than two '22' in the row, and 2) more than two '14' in the column.  Scan the array looking for 22 or 14.  Note that it is much more efficient to read each number from the array once and do all comparisons, since once the value is in CPU cache, the other comparisons are "free". The two bitmasks will be the '22' bitmask and the '14' bitmask.

There are fairly obvious algorithms for finding more than one bit in a row or column.  For an R x C matrix.

```
A1[C]
A2[C]
for r in 0 .. R-1
   A2 |= (A1 & Matrix.row(r))
   A1 |= Matrix.row(r)
```

At the end, A2 will be a mask of all columns with two or more bits.  To find numbers greater than two, just add A3, etc.

Comment: how was thinking about bit mask cheeking but i don't know exactly how to implement the pattern that in one scan pass it will get all the matchs